# TypeError - Int object not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

As part of an assignment, I've been trying to create a function which will create n new lines—but I can't figure out for the life of me how to fix this error.
Here's the code snippet:

```
def newLines(lines):
    for i in lines:
        print()

print("This is a string")
newLines(2)
print("This is also a string")
```

..which returns:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `for i in range(lines)` is what you're after. `for i in lines` requires `lines` to be something that you can iterate through, which `int`s don't support.

Comment: Thank you! So, you need a range to iterate through, and not just a single object... right?

Comment: It depends on the object. `int`s don't support iteration; `list`s, `str`s and `range`s are.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks again :)

Comment: Next to your profile picture is the one from the person who last edited your post (assuming it wasn't you). Above that is a line `edited...`, click that to see how your post was improved upon, and try to learn from that. Welcome to [so]